# Select comma-separated records from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, select-query

Table :  **frei_session**

```
id  username        accountId   status  status_mesg

14  Sumit Bijvani   50          0       I am available
16  Dilip Borad     49          1       I am available
15  Karan Bijvani   51          1       I am available
```

Table :  **users**

```
accountId    friends

49           50,52
50           49,52,51,44
51           50
```

I have 2 tables, **frei_session** have records of online users and **users** table have data of users and friends of them separated ID by comma.

I want to retrieve data from **frei_session** table based on **friends** column of **users** table.

**For Ex**

If `user 49` is online, I want **Output** like below

```
id  username        accountId   status  status_mesg

14  Sumit Bijvani   50          0       I am available
```

Because User 50 and 52 is friend of User 49 but now only User 50 is online

I have tried following query on single table but don't know how to do with 2 tables

```
SELECT DISTINCT status_mesg,username,session_id,status,guest
    FROM frei_session
    WHERE accountId!=49
    AND guest=0
    AND status!=2
    AND status!=0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your table is not normalize an considered as bad schema design. Anyway, to answer your question directly, `MySQL` has a builtin function called `FIND_IN_SET` which searches for a specific value on a CSV format.

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN frei_session b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.accountID, a.friends) > 0
WHERE   b.status = 0 AND
        a.accountID = 49
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5807d/4)

Comment: thank you very much. can you please give me some advice on normalize table?

Comment: one more thing. If I have same record in frei_session. Like `accountID = 50` is stored 2 times. so how can I just retrieve only 1 record from multiple records?

Comment: and what record do you want to retrieve if both are online/

Comment: yes like in `frei_session` table I have multiple records stored in same accountID. accountID=50 is stored two times. so I want to retrieve it just one time

Comment: and these records have the same `AccountID` and `username`?

Comment: check this sqlfiddle : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aeb8a/1 ... I dont want 2 records. I want only 1 record

Comment: thank you very much JW. Once again you have solved my query. this is the 3rd accepted answer of yours. you are genius man.

Comment: hey you have deleted your last question but here's the answer to that http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/763ce/10